# How To Use Multiple Cache Folder In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-3

I have a multiple language website I want to create a specific cache folder for every language. How Can I do this?
I currently using one cache folder with this code.

**Can You Help Me?**

```
$lang = $CI->session->userdata('language');
$cache_path .= md5($uri).'-'.$lang;
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple folders? One works just fine because the cache is mapped to the user session

Comment: If user want to change language of the website. that need to remove all cache and then change the language . also my website is two directional RTL & LTR . so i need to folder for cache and prevent from removing cache in change of language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find a solution. we must edit `output.php` in core folder like this.

```
        public function _write_cache($output){
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $lang = $CI->session->userdata('language');
            $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
            $cache_path = ($path === '') ? APPPATH.'cache_'.$lang.'/' : $path;
            //other code
        }
        public function _display_cache(&$CFG, &$URI){
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $lang = $CI->session->userdata('language');
            $cache_path = ($CFG->item('cache_path') === '') ? APPPATH.'cache_'.$lang.'/' : $CFG->item('cache_path');
            //other code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter that configures the cache folder is in `config.php` and its called `cache_path`. For modifying in during runtime, we can use the `$this->config->set_item` function. Obviously, the cache folder switch should be done as early as possible in the controller function, before the caching function call.

Here is a sample implementation, controller `Test`:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_language = 'french';

        $this->config->set_item('cache_path', 'IS_ROOT/cache/' . $user_language . '/');

        $this->output->cache(1);

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

when you run it, you can see in the logs, that the directory "french" under the "global" IS_ROOT/cache was used:

```
INFO - 2018-06-09 22:12:39 --> File loaded: /php_basedir/CodeIgniter_3_1_8/application/views/welcome_message.php
DEBUG - 2018-06-09 22:12:39 --> Cache file written: IS_ROOT/cache/french/bc3ad60292ed776397da07cac67ddd28
INFO - 2018-06-09 22:12:39 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2018-06-09 22:12:39 --> Total execution time: 0.0138
```

hope it helps